# sqlite join returning null even when both subqueries says otherwise

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I'm trying to run join on two tables in a sqlite database using subqueries(with/as). When I run the subqueries independently the value where ON clause is working exists in both tables yet when I apply a LEFT OUTER JOIN it gives null for those.
[image]

```
    
with transactionsData as (select (fee+amount) as chargedToCustomer,cast(substr(created,1,2) as decimal) as month,cast(substr(created,4,2) as decimal) as day from cardPayInvoices),
invoicesData as (select "Invoice Date",cast(substr(Amount,2) as decimal) as amountOnInvoice,
CASe substr(customerExcels."Invoice Date",1,3)
    WHEN "Jan"
        Then 1
    WHEN "Feb"
        Then 2
    WHEN "Mar"
        Then 3
    WHEN "Apr"
        Then 4
    WHEN "May"
        Then 5
    WHEN "Jun"
        Then 6
    WHEN "Jul"
        Then 7
    WHEN "Aug"
        Then 8
    WHEN "Sep"
        Then 9
    WHEN "Oct"
        Then 10
    WHEN "Nov"
        Then 11
    WHEN "Dec"
        Then 12
END monthFromDate           ,CAST( REPLACE(SUBSTR(customerExcels."Invoice Date",5,2),",","") as decimal) as dateOfMonthOnInvoice
 from customerExcels  where "Customer Group"="General" or "Customer Group" like "%OT LOGGED%")


select      distinct t.*,a.* from transactionsData  AS t LEFT JOIN invoicesData as a ON t.month=a.monthFromDate AND t.day=a.dateOfMonthOnInvoice AND t.chargedToCustomer=a.amountOnInvoice
```

I have tried literally everything I could think of, I've checked for trailing blankspaces and what not and yet i cant find the solution

table a(from subquery)
[image]

table t(from subquery)
[image]

Scheme

```
CREATE TABLE cardPayInvoices ( 
[id] nvarchar(500) ,
[created] nvarchar(500) ,
[description] nvarchar(500) ,
[currency] nvarchar(500) ,
[fee] nvarchar(500) ,
[amount] nvarchar(500) ,
[origin] nvarchar(500) ,
[originId] nvarchar(500) )



CREATE TABLE customerExcels ( 
[Invoice #] nvarchar(500) ,
[Invoice Date] nvarchar(500) ,
[Bill to Name] nvarchar(500) ,
[Customer Group] nvarchar(500) ,
[Amount] nvarchar(500) )


dummy values: cardPayInvoices 
insert into cardpayinvoices(id,created,description,currency,fee,amount,origin,originID) values(
"xxxx"  "07/01/2020 23:47:00"   "Capture (€294.30)" "EUR"   "20.86" "273.44"    "Transaction"   "xxxx")


customerExcel
insert into customerExcel("invoice #","invoice Date","Bill To Name","Customer Group","Amount") values(
"IT20-xxxx" "May 1, 2020 6:53:49 AM"    "ABC DEF"       "General"   "€103.79"),
("EN20-xxxx" "May 1, 2020 9:29:53 AM"   "GEH  IJK"  "General"   "€103.20"),
(EN20-xxxx May 1, 2020 1:41:18 PM   LMN OPQ     NOT LOGGED IN   €106.75)
```

Comment: That is the expected behavior or a `left join`. Try using `join` and it will not be null.

Comment: @rainisalt join doesnt give the row with 155.99 at all, this is why left join was used.. What I expect both JOIN and LEFT JOIN to return is a row with al lthese values since these column cells exist on both tables.

Comment: @Strawberry (?) Is there anything obvious that I'm missing? I've been slamming my head on this for hours now.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @strawberry Thank you! I've attached some example of dummy data(making sure the format remains intact) and the table schema.Would this be enough?

Comment: Probably. But I don't know SQLite

Comment: @ShahabUddin The sample data that you posted are **not** indicative of the problem. Post sample data preferably in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 where we can see that the joins do not work.

Comment: @forpas Thank you! The problem was with dbSQlite which was displaying the decimal values to only two significant figures so 55.951 and 55.959 were both being display the same on a select query while the join failed because it wasnt rounding off. Adding ROUND() to both columns used on ON expression fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took longer that I like to admit but after endless hours i found the solution
ROUND(fee+amount,2)

I am using DBSQLITE for displaying the result of queries and it always rounds it off to two digits on display so 15.99 and 15.99000000001 (in second table) was both shown as 15.99 yet on comparison at ON clause of my JOIN statement it failed.

Had to run the query through python's sqlite module and get the output to figure out what was wrong. Lesson learned: never trust dbSqlite or any other sqlite DB explorer tool.